# Добавить в сериализованный массив данные

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, сериализация

Блок с повторяющимися полями вида

```
поле | поле | поле
```

хранит массив в сериализованном виде вот так (текст полей заменил, поэтому в примере ниже количество символов `s` не соответствует содержанию, просто пример):

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"name";s:35:"Название 1";s:4:"date";s:10:"29.07.2018";s:4:"desc";s:155:"Описание 1";}}
```

Нужно туда добавить еще блок.

Я делаю следующее:

**1.** Достаю массив из БД и сую в переменную

```
$old_data = get_post_meta($postid, 'field_name', false);
```

**2.** Десериализую полученную строку:

```
$old_data_deser = unserialize($old_data);
```

**3.** Готовлю новый массив данных, который нужно добавить к старым

```
$new_data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Название 2',
    'date' => '29.07.2018',
    'desc' => 'Описание 2',
  ),
);
```

**4.** Добавляю одно к другому

```
$res = array_merge($old_data_deser, $new_data);
```

**5.** Сохраняю получившееся в БД. (т.к. функция сама сериализует данные, то я отдаю ей просто массив)

```
update_post_meta( $postid, 'field_name', $res );
```

В результате получаю вместо данных `NULL` в БД.

Вопросов несколько:

1. Правильный ли вариант работы с сериализованными данными? Сразу в сериализованную строку что-то вставить возможности нет?
2. Почему получаю `NULL`? Где ошибка в коде? **РЕШЕНО, не актуально**

Comment: Ну да, все так. Руками десериализовать не надо. Оформите upd в виде ответа.

Comment: @KAGGDesign оформил как ответ. Долго возился, никак не мог понять в чём проблема... Вопрос оформления в цикле `foreach` фигурные скобки в данном случае нужны или их можно удалить? Тут как бы разбора на значения и вывода инфы ведь нет. И Второй вопрос (первый из топика) - с сериализованной строкой средств для работы нет (я про дополнение, которое нужно в данной ситуации)?

Comment: Фигурные скобки содержат произвольное количество инструкций, выполняемых в цикле. Если вы их уберёте, в цикле будет выполняться только одна инструкция, сразу за foreach. Использование foreach без {} крайне не рекомендуется стандартами кодирования.

Comment: Работа с сериализованными данными правильная. Руками лезть в строку не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Мало ли, кто-то еще столкнется с чем-то подобным.

Касательно `NULL` - функция `get_post_meta` возвращает десериализованный массив, я этот момент упустил. Поэтому после ручной десериализации получал пустоту. Пункт 2 лишний.

Касательно добавления нового массива в этот многомерный массив.
Значит у нас уже есть десериализованный массив.
Поднимаем его на один уровень вверх (убираем один array) циклом
`foreach ($old_data as $old_data_up) {  }`

Потом уже пункт 3-5. В итоге будет `array -> array [0] -> array с данными`.